# Limiting a query based on output

Tags: mysql

I'm writing code for a sports situation where the query returns who conceded the least goals.

```
SELECT t.user AS userid, t.team AS teamid, dteam.name AS teamname, l.id AS leagueid, l.name AS leaguename, l.season AS leagueseason, l.career AS careerid
FROM tbl_foot_tables t
INNER JOIN tbl_foot_career_teams team ON t.team = team.id
INNER JOIN tbl_foot_career_db_teams dteam ON dteam.id = team.teamid
INNER JOIN tbl_foot_leagues l ON l.id = t.league
WHERE t.league = 263
ORDER BY t.home_goals_against + t.away_goals_against LIMIT 1
```

I limit is to 1 because I want the player who conceded the least. However, in a scenario where 2/3/4 players all conceded the same amount of goals, I need it to return all of these rows.

If I don't limit, I'll return all rows, even with different amounts of goals conceded.

I'm unaware of what to do in this situation as I've never come across it before.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calculating the best goals in a subquery and using a `join` to get the value.  Then choose all teams that match this:

```
SELECT t.user AS userid, t.team AS teamid, dteam.name AS teamname, l.id AS leagueid,
       l.name AS leaguename, l.season AS leagueseason, l.career AS careerid
FROM tbl_foot_tables t INNER JOIN
     tbl_foot_career_teams team
     ON t.team = team.id INNER JOIN
     tbl_foot_career_db_teams dteam
     ON dteam.id = team.teamid INNER JOIN
     tbl_foot_leagues l
     ON l.id = t.league join
     (select t.home_goals_against + t.away_goals_against as goals
      from tbl_foot_tables t
      WHERE t.league = 263
      order by  t.home_goals_against + t.away_goals_against desc
      limit 1
     ) as thebest
     on  t.home_goals_against + t.away_goals_against = thebest.goals
WHERE t.league = 263 ;
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks bud. I'll take note that whenever this type of scenario comes up where I need information before running the query, I'll run a subquery and join :)